# Zend Form create button link

Tags: zend-framework

I have Zend_Form with button type element. i don't how to use onclick type from zend_form.

**Index.phtml**

[Search](http://my_search_location_path)

**Zend_Form**

```
$Search = new Zend_Form_Element_Submit('Search');
    $Search->setAttrib('ID', 'searchbutton');
    $Search->setDecorators(array('ViewHelper'));
```

Here using this zend form how to perform the onclick action using search button.could you please any one help on this?

Thanks for advice!

Answer (score 1):

Hey you would have to do something like this

```
$Search = new Zend_Form_Element_Submit('Search');
$Search->setAttrib('ID', 'searchbutton');
$Search->setDecorators(array('ViewHelper'));

$form = new Zend_Form('FormExample');
$form->setAction('destination.php');
$form->setMethod('POST');
$form->addElement($Search);
$form->setView(new Zend_View());
print($form);
```

If you have other elements than the $Search you just have to addElements as an array, like this:

```
$form->addElements([$Search,$Element1, $Element2]);
```

Comment: Hi Jefferson, Here i am not understand $form->setAction('destination.php'); what is mean that, how to i use ?

Comment: @user6420577 every submitt button has an action inside a Form,  in this case setAction was used is to navigate to another page.